# Can't get to empty paragraphs in contentEditable

Tags: javascript, css, html, contenteditable

I have a contentEditable article, with "EmbeddedSection" div's (recursive) which have a paragraph above and below them. In chrome, if the paragraph is empty, you can't actually get to it. In IE you can, but the size is all wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/hE8zS/1/

```
<article contenteditable="true">
   <p><span class="numbering">Title</span><span class="TextChunk"></span></p>
   <div class="EmbeddedSection">
       <p><span class="numbering">1</span><span class="TextChunk">Section Title</span></p>   
       <div class="EmbeddedSection">
           <p><span class="numbering">1.1</span><span class="TextChunk">Embedded title</span></p>
           <p><span class="TextChunk">Th</span><span class="TextChunk">e </span><span class="TextChunk">.</span></p>
       </div>
       <p><span class="TextChunk"></span></p> <!--Can't get to this element-->
       <div class="EmbeddedSection">
           <p class="Paragraph"><span class="numbering">1.2</span><span class="TextChunk">Another title</span></p>
           <p class="Paragraph"><span class="TextChunk">Blah blah blah</span></p>
       </div>
       <p><span class="TextChunk">Can get here, but not the one above 1.2 in chrome (ie gets there).</span></p>
       <div class="EmbeddedSection">
           <p class="Paragraph"><span class="numbering">1.3</span><span class="TextChunk">Another title</span></p>
           <p class="Paragraph"><span class="TextChunk">Blah blah blah</span></p>
        </div>
        <p><span class="TextChunk"></span></p> <!--Can't get to this element-->
    </div>
</article>
```

Does anybody know if I'm able to style the empty paragraphs or somehow mark them as something which enables them to be reachable?

(Note: putting even a single whitespace character works, even after the user has edited and removed that whitespace character.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add

```
:empty {
    display: block;
    height: 1em;
}
```

And it seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/hE8zS/3/

This page contains information on browser compatibility: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty

Comment: You can also target it using `[contenteditable]:focus :empty`, then any other empty elements will remain hidden.

Comment: Awesome. Do you know how I can make it look like those elements have been selected? If you select those empty elements there is no visual feedback to show you that those bits are selected. e.g. if you highlight from the empty element up, you can see the elements above are highlighted, but the empty element shows nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Simple placeholder for contenteditables:

```
[contenteditable]:empty::before {
    content: 'Your Placeholder Text';
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've actually moved on from using :empty as it doesn't select right and doesn't play nice with contenteditable.

I actually ended up putting in a zero-width whitespace in any paragraph that was empty (and some associated javascript to skip it on keypress), meaning it sizes it correctly, and plays nicely with contenteditables. See my bug report for chrome here http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=292334